# Nested Templates, Finding Parent

Tags: templates, nested, meteor

I have a series of nested objects.  Say like... stores and items.

I have perhaps 10 stores, each with the same 10 items, displayed on the screen at the same time.

```
<template name='store'>
  {{#each items}}
   {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
</template>


<template name='item'>
  {{name}} {{qty}}
</template>
```

The main problem I have is trying to determine {{qty}} using a helper function.  This is because the item inherently does not have a 'quantity', but rather it depends on which "store" it is related to.  So I'd need to find the quantity based on the "store" + "item".

What's the "meteor way" of searching for this?  Is it to store a bunch of data -* attributes in the DOM and search out my mongdb _id items via Jquery?  I don't think mustache allows you to figure out where you came from and access a "parent scope's variables".  And it's not like backbone where I can just add that link from the parent-store view to the child-item views.

I don't feel comfortable using session variables because I'm worried that that may cause race conditions (such as Session.get('current_store_id')).

Thanks!

Comment: Will you display multiple stores on one page? (Wrt the race conditions)

Comment: Yes, multiple stores on the same page at the same time. Here's a slightly more documented example: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/147

Answer (score 2):

Handlebars supports `../` in paths, which might help:

http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the github issue, I created the following function (coffeescript) and it solved the event-handling issue: parentContext = (node) ->
 context = Meteor.ui._LiveRange.findRange Meteor.ui._tag, node;
 return null unless (parent = do context.findParent)?;
 return parent.event_data;