# How to access outer {{#each}} collection value in the nested loop

Tags: meteor

What is the standard way to access outer #each collection values in the loop?
for example:

```
<template name="example">
  {{#each outerCollection}}
  <tr>
    {{#each innerCollection}}
      <td>{{aaa}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.example.aaa = function(){
  // cannot access outerCollection values
}
```

in above Template.example.aaa, `this` points to the inner collection.

I cannot find way to access outerCollection items.
My solution is like below, I am defining my own helper function. 
Is it a standard Meteor way to achieve this purpose?

```
<template name="example">
  {{#each outerCollection}}
  <tr>
    {{#each innerCollection}}
      <td>{{myHelper ../outerItem innerItem}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelper', function (outItem, inItem) {
  // can access outerCollection via outerItem
});
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091914/meteor-how-to-access-parent-properties-within-nested-templates) for the case of inner event handler access.

Comment: I think that's it. What is the question exactly?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I posted this question is because I don't have confidence for my code and cannot find meteor sample code for this purpose. I want to know if anyone knows more clever implementation.

Comment: Here is better way, no need registerHelper as above, following syntax can work: Template.example.myHelper = function(outItem, inItem){ /* can access outerCollection item via outItem */ };

Comment: This might also help: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789622/accessing-parent-context-in-meteor-templates-and-template-helpers/13851721#13851721][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789622/accessing-parent-context-in-meteor-templates-and-template-helpers/13851721#13851721

Answer (score 12):

I think you've answered this yourself! Using `../` is documented in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars.

Comment: But how do you get {{aaa}} in the js ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to fetch outer collections.

suppose you have collection called as **Collection.Customer** and **Collection.RechargePlan** and you are using both in a template for updating Customer.

```
Customer = {"name":"James", "rechargeplan":"monthly"};
RechargePlan = [{"rechargeplan": "monthly"},{"rechargeplan": "yearly"}];

 //Inside template, Bydefault Customer is available.
{{#each RechargePlan}}
  {{#if equals ../rechargeplan rechargeplan}}
      //Hurray Plan matches
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

In above code, **../rechargeplan** is actually **Customer.rechargeplan**, ../ actually went one step above heirarchy and then accessed the field if available, since Customer is already available to template, it's field is picked up.