# Accessing parent context in Meteor templates and template helpers

Tags: meteor

I'm running into a template context situation that I'm having a hard time finding a way around.

**Here's the template in question:**

```
{{#each votes}}
    <h3>{{question}}</h3>

    <ul>
        {{#each participants}}
            <li>
                <p>{{email}}</p>
                <select name="option-select">
                    {{#each ../options}}
                    <option value="{{option}}" class="{{is_selected_option}}">{{option}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

**And here's an example of a vote document:**

```
{
    _id: '32093ufsdj90j234',
    question: 'What is the best food of all time?'
    options: [
        'Pizza',
        'Tacos',
        'Salad',
        'Thai'
    ],
    participants: [
        {
            id: '2f537a74-3ce0-47b3-80fc-97a4189b2c15'
            vote: 0
        },
        {
            id: '8bffafa7-8736-4c4b-968e-82900b82c266'
            vote: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**And here's the issue...**

When the template drops into the `#each` for participants, it no longer has access to the `vote` context, and therefore doesn't have access to the available options for each vote.

I can *somewhat* get around this by using the `../options` handlebars path to jump back into the parent context, but this doesn't affect the context of the template helper, so `this` in `Template.vote.is_selected_option` refers to the current `participant`, not to the current `vote` or `option`, and has no way of knowing which `option` we are currently iterating through.

Any suggestions on how to get around this, without resorting to DOM manipulation and jQuery shenanigans?

This is a templating issue that has come up multiple times for me. We need a formal way of reaching up the template context hierarchy, in templates, template helpers, and template events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not particularly pretty, but I've done something like this:

```
<template name='forLoop'>
{{#each augmentedParticipants}}
{{> participant }}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name='participant'>
...
Question: {{this.parent.question}}
...
</template>


// and in the js:
Template.forLoop.helpers({
    augmentedParticipants: function() {
        var self = this;
        return _.map(self.participants,function(p) {
            p.parent = self;
            return p;
        });
    }
});
```

It's similar to the approach that AVGP suggested, but augments the data at the helper level instead of the db level, which I think is a little lighter-weight.

If you get fancy, you could try to write a Handlebars block helper `eachWithParent` that would abstract this functionality.  Meteor's extensions to handlebars are documented here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars

Comment: zorlak: What I ended up doing is pretty similar to your example: created an augmented `participants_with_vote_info` collection that included everything I needed, and iterated through that with `#each` so that I didn't need to jump back up into the parent. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: For a deep nested template layout this is quite a pain in the ass

Answer (score 84):

It seems since [Spacebars (Meteor's new template engine)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#identifiers-and-paths), you have access to the parent context within `{{#each}}` blocks using `../`.

In Meteor 0.9.1, you can also write a helper and use [`Template.parentData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_parentdata) in its implementation.

Comment: @opyh, will you add a reference to [Template.parentData(numLevels)](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_parentdata)? I think it would improve this answer even further.

Comment: So you would do `<template name='participant'>
Question: {{../question}}
</template>` this worked for me. (Meteor 1.0+)

Comment: Just to note, you can access the parent context in any block, and you can reference an property like this like {{#if ../someProperty}}

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the formal way (if there is one), but to solve your issue, I would link the participants with the parent ID like this:

```
{
    _id: "1234",
    question: "Whats up?",
    ...
    participants: [
      {
        _id: "abcd",
        parent_id: "1234",
        vote: 0
      }
    ]
}
```

and use this parent_id in helpers, events, etc. to jump back to the parent using findOne.
That is obviously a sub optimal thing to do, but it's the easiest way that comes to my mind as long as there is no way of referencing the parent context.
Maybe there is a way but it is very well hidden in the inner workings of Meteor without mention in the docs, if so: Please update this question if you find one.

Comment: You're right, this would be sub-optimal but it would work. A similar alternative would be to use a separate Users collection, with each User storing their related vote id. If anybody else has other ways of doing this _please_ let me know.

Comment: I should add, neither of these solutions gets around the _biggest_ problem, that each `Template.votes.option` in `{{#each ../options}}` doesn't know which option it actually refers to!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's a long shot, but maybe this could work:

```
{{#with ../}}
  {{#each options}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should make life easier.

```
// use #eachWithParent instead of #each and the parent._id will be passed into the context as parent.
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachWithParent', function(context, options) {

    var self = this;
    var contextWithParent = _.map(context,function(p) {
        p.parent = self._id;
        return p;
    });

    var ret = "";

    for(var i=0, j=contextWithParent.length; i<j; i++) {
        ret = ret + options.fn( contextWithParent[i] );
    }
    return ret;
});
```

Go ahead and change

```
p.parent = self._id;
```

to whatever you want to access in the parent context.

Fixed it:

```
// https://github.com/meteor/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/base.js

// use #eachWithParent instead of #each and the parent._id will be passed into the context as parent.
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachWithParent', function(context, options) {
    var self = this;
    var contextWithParent = _.map(context,function(p) {
        p.parent = self._id;
        return p;
    });

    return Handlebars._default_helpers.each(contextWithParent, options);
});
```

This works :) with no error

Comment: I get this error `Exception from Deps afterFlush function: Error: Can't create second landmark in same branch` when I try to change something thats rendered with eachWithParent

Answer (score 2):

Simply register a global template helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('parentData',
    function () {
        return Template.parentData(1);
    }
);
```

and use it in your HTML templates as:

```
{{#each someRecords}}
  {{parentData.someValue}}
{{/each}}
```

======= EDIT

For Meteor 1.2+, you shold use:

```
UI.registerHelper('parentData', function() {
  return Template.parentData(1);
});
```

Comment: but what is "someRecords" in your example? surely that has to be from the parentData context - but your solution doesn't appear to work when you try to access parentData in the #each clause

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar way and found that the Template.parentData() approach suggested in other answers currently doesn't work within event handlers (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5491). User Lirbank posted this simple workaround:

Pass the data from the outer context to an html element in the inner context, in the same template:

```
{{#each companies}}
  {{#each employees}}
    <a href="" companyId="{{../id}}">Do something</a>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Now the company ID can be accessed from the event handler with something like

```
$(event.currentTarget).attr('companyId')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
"click .selected":function(e){
    var parent_id = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr("uid");
    return parent_id
  },
```

```html
<td id="" class="staff_docs" uid="{{_id}}">
                                        {{#each all_req_doc}}
                                                <div class="icheckbox selected "></div>
  {{/each}}
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{#each parent}}`

`{{#each child}}`

`<input type="hidden" name="child_id" value="{{_id}}" />`

`<input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{../_id}}" />`

`{{/each}}`

`{{/each}}`

The _id is NOT the _did of the thing, it's the id of the parent!