# meteor: using nested each-loops

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have some problems with understanding using each-loops in meteor. As I have the following SimpleSchema for my DB...

**collection.js**

```
dGroup = new SimpleSchema({
    title:      { type: String, optional: true },
    element:    { type: [more], optional: true }
});

more = new SimpleSchema({
    description: { type: String, optional: true },
    anything:   { type: String, optional: true }
});

MongoDB.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    mainTitle:  { type: String },
    slug:       { type: String, unique: true },
    language:   { type: String, defaultValue: "en" },
    group:      { type: [dGroup], optional: true },
}));
```

**router.js**

```
data: function () {
    return { 
         result: MongoDB.findOne({
            _id: this.params._id
        }) 
    };
}
```

... and I want to use an each-loop in an each-loop:

```
{{#each result.group}}
<table>
    <caption>{{mainTitle}}</caption>
    <tbody>
        {{#each element}}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{description}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{anything}}"></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
{{/each}}
```

**Update**

My problem is how to use elements, which are in the parent elements. In this example I don't get access to the `{{mainTitle}}` as it is a parent element of the while-loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing parent context in Meteor templates and template helpers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789622/accessing-parent-context-in-meteor-templates-and-template-helpers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the parent data context using `../`, for example:

```
{{#each result.group}}
  <table>
    <caption>{{mainTitle}}</caption>
    <tbody>
      {{#each element}}
        <tr>
          <th> {{../mainTitle}} </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" value="{{description}}"></td>
          <td><input type="text" value="{{anything}}"></td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{{/each}}
```