# Meteor access parent each value

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I have nested each and want to use parent `this` value.

```
{{#each county}}
        Country name : {{this}}
    {{#each state}}
        {{this}} is one of the state of {{country}} //here how to use country
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I have tried `{{../this}}` but it shows

```
Can only use `this` at the beginning of a path.
Instead of `foo.this` or `../this`, just write `foo` or `..`.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing parent context in Meteor templates and template helpers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789622/accessing-parent-context-in-meteor-templates-and-template-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

simply you can do

```
{{#each county}}
  Country name : {{this}}
 {{#each state}}
    {{this}} is one of the state of {{..}} //here how to use country
 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

see `{{..}}`

**EDIT**: edited answer

Comment: I have tried `{{../this}}` can you look at my edited question?.

Comment: it is {{..}} one closing bracket was missing in previous comment

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!