# Dynamic object path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, meteor

I'm struggling a bit on a common javascript issue, mostly because I don't know the key words to find the solution in Google.
What I would like to do in pure javascript :

```
var obj = {label: 'Name', type: 'text', position: 0};
var name = 'label';

var temp = obj."name" // = obj.label = Name
```

And use it in meteorJS template :

```
data = [ 
  {
     "Name" : "Task 1",
     "CreationDate" : ISODate("2014-06-03T19:47:48.252Z"),
     "EndDate" : ISODate("2014-07-03T19:47:48.252Z")
  }, 
  {
     "Name" : "Task 2",
     "CreationDate" : ISODate("2014-06-04T19:47:48.252Z"),
     "EndDate" : ISODate("2014-07-04T19:47:48.252Z")
  }
}

columns = [
        {label: 'Name'},
        {label: 'Creation Date'},
        {label: 'End Date'}
    ]

{{#each data}}
  <tr>
    {{#each columns}}
      <td>{{data.label}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You're looking for ["bracket notation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Just to expand on @elclanrs comment, working off the first example you gave: obj[name] or obj['label'] are equal to 'Name'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

So for my first question (pure javascript syntax) its ok. Thanks

```
var obj = {label: 'Name', type: 'text', position: 0};
var name = 'label';
var temp = obj[name];  //Works fine
```

For my second question, this way is working (inspired by [How to access outer {{#each}} collection value in the nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687065/how-to-access-outer-each-collection-value-in-the-nested-loop)) :

```
{{#each data}}
    <tr>
        {{#each columns}}
            <td>{{attr .. label}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}

Template.worksheets.helpers({
    attr : function (outItem, inItem) {
        return outItem[inItem];
    }
});
```

But its a bit ugly ...

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of asking a new question as an answer.