# METEOR JS. A variable in each loop

Tags: javascript, meteor

**HTML**

```html
<template name="contact">
  ...
  {{> FORMULAIRE descrip =descripFormContact }}
  ...
</template>

<template name="FORMULAIRE" >
  <form id={{descrip.idForm}} >
    <fieldset id="idFieldSet{{descrip.idForm}}">
      {{#each descrip.champs}}
        <span id="idSpanLabel{{descrip.idForm}}" ....>{{this.label}}</span>
      ...
      
      {{/each}}
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
Template.contact.helpers({
        descripFormContact: {
            idForm: 'formContact',
            champs: [{
                nomChp: 'prenom', label: 'Prenom : ', type: 'text', oblig:true,
            }]
        }
})
```

All is OK but I can't seem to find the value of "descrip.idForm" in the loop "each".

Can someone tell me why, in the loop "each", "descrip.idForm" is empty, then that the outside of the loop is equal to "formContact"

Thank you for your answer

YC

Comment: Try prefixing the expression with `../`, to get the outer scope (i.e, `{{../descrip.idForm}}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access outer {{#each}} collection value in the nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687065/how-to-access-outer-each-collection-value-in-the-nested-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove the space between descript and = in your FORMULAIRE template call.

Regs,yann