# How Do I Access a Parent's Data Attribute in Meteor Template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I was trying to extend an application and found out that whenever I try to access the _id value from inside an #if clause, it always returns empty...

This example returns the {{_../id}}:

```
<template name="showsId">
  {{# each comments}}
    <div class="id">{{../_id}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But this one doesn't:

```
<template name="doesNotShowId">
  {{# each comments}}
    {{#if editingComments}}
      <div class="id">{{../_id}}</div>
    {{else}}
      <div class="id">{{../_id}}</div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Do you know why this might be happening? As far as I know this should work as expected.

EDIT:

This is a template that's being called from another one, in this fashion:

```
<template name="statusitems">
  <div>
    {{#each statusItem}}
  <div>
    {{> statusComments }}
  </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>    
</template>
```

That's why I'm asking for the {{../_id}}.

Comment: I doubt that `{{../_id}}` will work in the current release of **Meteor** (0.7.0.1), but I would recommend switching to some experimental branch like `shark` for example. I am pretty much sure the feature you need is implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

For both data contexts, the comment document seems to be provided by the each iterator.

Therefore, I believe you should not be using ../ anyway since the document properties suchs as _id are already provided within the data context.

This should work as is:

```
<template name="doesNotShowId">
  {{# each comments}}
    {{#if editingComments}}
      <div class="id">{{_id}}</div>
    {{else}}
      <div class="id">{{_id}}</div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

So should this:

```
<template name="doesNotShowId">
  {{# each comments}}
    <div class="id">{{_id}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Probably I should have stated that these are documents inside another document, I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Hm,I should have realized that. Anyway ../_id should have been working then. Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789622/accessing-parent-context-in-meteor-templates-and-template-helpers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091914/meteor-how-to-access-parent-properties-within-nested-templates) can help.