# Meteor- pass data to nested templates

Tags: templates, meteor, nested, handlebars.js

Meteor newbie here.

I have a template for a home page. The home pages has several "day"s in it, which each have "task"s. I want to display the appropriate task in the day that it belongs to, but I don't know how to do this.

I also only want to retrieve the relevant tasks with one database query if possible (ie all tasks within two weeks).

I found a couple other questions possibly related to this including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091914/meteor-how-to-access-parent-properties-within-nested-templates) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654255/nested-templates-finding-parent) but I can't discern any useful related info.

I have a collection for tasks, and as part of the home page I retrieve a two week span of tasks. Then I sort them into day buckets.

```
buckets = [[...], [...], [...], ... ] # array of arrays of task objects
```

Now I don't know what to do. In the home template, I think I can do

```
Template.home.helpers(
    tasks: ()->
        #return buckets, defined above
)
(home.coffee)

<template name="home">
    {{#each tasks}}
         {{> day}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
(home.html)
```

to iterate over the day buckets, but how do I access the task objects from each day template?

```
<template name="day">
    {{#each ???}}
        {{> task}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="task">
    {{name}}
</template>
```

How can I access the data from the current iteration of the each loop from the parent template? Am I structuring this incorrectly? Should I just make separate db calls for every day?

Comment: I am glad you solved this problem, I saw your tweet too late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *should* do the trick:

```
<template name="day">
    {{#each this}}
        {{> task}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

---

**Edit:** this is the incorrect original answer.

Let `task` have fields called `name`, `important` and `dueToday`. Then you may write:

```
<template name="day">
  {{name}}
</template>
```

Or, if you insist:

```
<template name="day">
  {{this.name}}
</template>
```

Also:

```
Template.day.isItUrgent = function() {
  return this.data.important && this.data.dueToday;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, this might have been unclear, but each bucket is actually an array of Task objects. So I think if I did that, it would error, since I'm trying to find the name attribute of an array.

Comment: Didn't realize this referred to the input to each. Of course. Thanks!